What is conditional probability in this case

An electrical system consists of four components as illustrated in the figure below. The
system works if components A and B work and either of the components C or D
works. The reliability (probability of working) of each component is also shown
in the figure. Find the probability that (a) the entire system works and (b) the
component C does not work, given that the entire system works. Assume that the
four components work independently.


The answer to part (a), the probability that the entire system works, is 0.7776.
I am interested in part (b). I understand the textbook's solution,
$$
\frac{P(A \cap B \cap \overline{C} \cap  D)}{0.7776}.
$$ However, my thought process was, $P(\overline{C} | A \cap B  \cap  D ),$ since we're given that the system works and we want to find the probability of C not working. How is my reasoning incorrect, giving a different answer from the textbook's?

You aren't given that $A,B,D$ worked, all you are given is that the system worked.  A priori, there are three ways that could happen:  $ABCD,, AB\overline CD,,ABC\overline D$.  Those three cases sum to the answer from part $a$.  You are interested in the contribution to that sum from the desired case.

Your answer is
$$
P(\overline{C} | A \cap B  \cap  D )\\
=P\big(\overline C \mid \{\color\green{ABCD,AB\overline CD}\}\big)\\
=\frac{P\big(\{AB\overline CD\}\big)}{P\big(\{ABCD,AB\overline CD\}\big)}\\
=P(\overline C),$$ which is manifest at the outset seeing that $A,B,\overline C,D$ are mutually independent events.
On the other hand, the textbook's answer is
$$
P(\overline C \mid \text{the event that the system works})\\
=P\big(\overline C \mid \{\color\green{ABCD,}\color\red{ABC\overline D,}\color\green{AB\overline CD}\}\big)\\
=\frac{P\big(\{AB\overline CD\}\big)}{P\big(\{ABCD,ABC\overline D,AB\overline CD\}\big)}\\
=\frac{P\big(\{AB\overline CD\}\big)}{0.7776}\\
\ne P(\overline C).
$$
